# SML: Pattern Matching

Tags: pattern-matching, sml, type-mismatch

I have a little experience with SML and I am trying to make a scanner. I am stuck at the folowing CODE. Any help is appreciated.

```
- fun nextChar nil = NONE
    | nextChar (head::tail) = SOME (head, tail);
- val a = [#"a",#"b",#"d",#"c"];
- val (head, tail) = nextChar a;
```

I get an error regarding mismatch of pattern and expression return type. Can someone please point out on which pattern can I use to match the expression return type.

Error:

```
stdIn:7.5-7.28 Error: pattern and expression in val dec don't agree [tycon mismatch]
pattern:    'Z * 'Y
expression:    (char * char list) option
in declaration:
(head,tail) = nextChar a
stdIn:7.5-7.28 Warning: type vars not generalized because of
value restriction are instantiated to dummy types (X1,X2,...)
stdIn:7.5-7.28 Warning: type vars not generalized because of
value restriction are instantiated to dummy types (X1,X2,...)
```

Comment: `nextChar a` returns `SOME (#"a", [#"b", #"d", #"c"])`, and the type of this value (*char × char list) option*) will never unify with the type of the pattern in `val (head,tail) = ...` (being *'a × 'b*). If you wrote `val SOME (head, tail) = nextChar a`, it would work, but it is ill-adviced to deconstruct `SOME`/`NONE` in a let-binding, since one pattern will exclude the other and cause a run-time exception. Rather, you should use *case-of*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Simon wrote, you are going to need to check the return value of `nextChar` before you try to use it as a list. You are returning a `(char * char list) option` not a `char * char list`. You might want to pattern match on the result to check if it is a SOME tuple and then use it:

```
val it = case nextChar (a) of
    NONE => defaultChar
  | SOME (head, tail) => head;
```

Comment: You may also consider writing the function `safeHead [] = NONE | safeHead (x::xs) = SOME x`.